# Between us my sister and I know everything -- how many sisters do I have?

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

My name is Aaron. I used to think my twin brother Bernard and I were pretty smart. You see between us, we know everything.

That was until we met the triplets Charlotte, Denise, and Esther. Between any two of the sisters, they knew everything.

I asked Charlotte did she know are there any quadruplets or quintuplets who, between any pair, know everything. She doesn't know but that means we can ask Denise or Esther when we see them next. Unfortunately they are on holiday in Fiji. So I will ask the internet instead.

> **Problem:** Suppose we have a set $F=\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ of *facts*. Consider a family (haha, family) $\{F_1,\ldots, F_m\}$ of **distinct** subsets of $F$ where $F_i \neq F_j$ for $i\neq j$, i.e., each $F_i$ is distinct. We call the family *knowledgeable* to mean that for any distinct $F_i,F_j$ we have $F_i \cup F_j = F$. What is the largest cardinality of a knowledgeable family?

The answer is at least $n+1$, since you can have sets $F_i = F \setminus \{i\}$ and $F_{n+1}=F$.

Is the answer exactly $n+1$?

Comment: You have not said whether $F_i=F$ is possible (presumably not)

Comment: @Henry $F_i=F$ is allowed. It doesn't make a significant difference. It just raises the answer by one.

Comment: But then you must require that all the $F_i$ be distinct (else we could include infinitely many copies of $F$).  I think it's simpler if you disallow $F_i=F$ (as the other sorts of $F_i$ are obviously distinct).

Comment: If every individual can know everything then there is no limit on the number of members of the family with any pair knowing everything

Comment: And if $F_i=F$ is disallowed, then the map which takes an element of $F$ to the (necessarily) unique subset which does not contain it is surjective.  (note that we can always adjoin $F-\{i\}$ to the family if all the members of the family contain $i$)

Comment: @Henry But *every* pair $F_i, F_j$ must satisfy $F_i \cup F_j = F$ (I think OP needs to mandate that the $F_i$ are distinct but otherwise it seems ok,no?)

Comment: @lulu $F_i,F_j$  are required to be distinct.

Comment: Sure, but that isn't stated anywhere.  Like I say, if you disallow $F=F_i$ then it follows from your assumptions, but not otherwise.  To be clear:  I don't think this point is terribly important, just trying to clear up a possibly confusing point.

Comment: Saying nobody knows exactly the same things as somebody else seems more of a jump than saying  nobody knows everything (it is more natural to read *subset* as "proper subset" than as "distinct subset")

Comment: @lulu  I have edited the question to say explicitly that the elements of the family (haha, family) are distinct.

Comment: Let $G_i = \{1, \dots, n\} \setminus F_i$. Then $G_1, \dots, G_m$ are supposed to be pairwise disjoint. It's obvious you can have at most $n$ pairwise disjoint nonempty subsets of an $n$-element set.

Comment: On the other hand the phrasing of the question is rather poetic. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is well-suited for the pigeonhole principle. Assume there are $n+2$ people. Possibly, one of these people knows all of the facts; we set this person aside,  leaving at least $n+1$ people.

Each person is a pigeon. Each fact has a corresponding hole. Each person is placed into a pigeonhole corresponding to a fact they *do not know*. If a person does not know several facts, they choose one arbitrarily, and place themselves in that hole.

There are $n+1$ pigeons in $n$ holes. Some hole must have two pigeons, but this would mean there was a fact that was unknown by two people, so those two people do not know all the facts. Therefore, when we add back in the know-it-all set aside at the beginning any successful family can have at most $n+2$ people.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal F$ be a knowledgeable family. Let $I = F \setminus \bigcap \mathcal F$.

For each $i \in I$ we have $i \notin \bigcap \mathcal F$. So we have $i \notin F_i$ for some $F_i \in \mathcal F$.

We claim    $\mathcal F \subset \{F\} \cup \{F_i: i \in I\}$.

Let $G \in \mathcal F\setminus \{F\}$ be arbitrary. We have $j \notin G$ for some $j \in I$. Since we must have $G \cup F_j = F$ and both sets exclude $j$, the two sets must coincide.

So there is at most one element of $\mathcal F$ for each element of $I$. So there are at most $n$ proper elements of the family, plus one if $F$ itself is a member of the family.

It follows the largest family has $\bigcap \mathcal F = \varnothing$.